# HTML5 Performance - Add a <tr> to the middle of a table vs. end of table

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

I have a big table element, with about 2000 `<tr>`'s, each has about 20 `<td>`'s

When trying to add a new `<tr>` to the table, if added to the end via `.appendChild()`, element is added to DOM pretty quickly.

When trying to add a new `<tr>` to the middle of a table user `.insertBefore()` a huge style recalculation is triggered, can be up to 1000ms which is off course a terrible UX.

See JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/bonumezede/edit?html,js,output

Attaching a screenshot of Chrome DevTools Timeline. Adding three rows to top, then three rows to middle and finally three rows to the end of the table. As you can see, adding to the end is a lot faster.

[image]

I am aware that tables could be very slow, but I am maintaining an existing product and cannot change the markup.

Basically, my two questions are:

1. Why is adding to the bottom of the table is faster (might be because
   existing rows don't have to be moved?)
2. How can I optimize my table to better handle rows added to the top/middle?

Thanks

Comment: give as many columns a fixed width as possible to cut down on reflow. a max-height on rows can help to. basically, try to eliminate as much math as possible to fill in the table rows. sometimes, hiding the table while inserting then unhiding can help, but that trick has lost some steam over the past few years as browsers get more complex.

Comment: Can you maybe break the table in multiple separate tables? I suppose it would help with performance, and quite possibly with readability. Now the code would be more complex, and I guess it falls into the markup change category

Comment: A lighter version of Aaron's suggestion would be to display only a small portion of the table, the one which would be visible on the screen anyway. When user scrolls the table, change the visible part accordingly.

Comment: have you tried `table-layout: fixed;`?

Comment: Yes I have, doesn't really change performance

Answer (score 0):

When you insert at the end, new space is allocated and quickly assigned.  When you are inserting in the middle, a new row is created at the end and then all elements shift 1 to the right.

When you are adding at the end the redraw doesnt take much time at all if at all.  In the middle the redraw occurs because now things like items which were even and odd are now flipflopped, and css needs to be reapplied.